# Azure B2C user flows - accessibility issues on screen readers

Tags: dom, azure-ad-b2c, screen-readers, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

We currently have issues to make the B2C user flows accessible from a screen reader perspective.
All the DOM ingested by the MS user flows in junction with our html/css UI files makes impossible for a screen reader to don´t crash or work with normality.

Has someone a better insight in how to overcome these issues using B2C user flows? Any workarounds or alternatives?

Thanks and Regards